# How can I isolate a section of a path

Tags: python, path, extract

I'm wanting to extract the path that contains the word `"tk-nuke-writenode"` in it in the example below.

I need to isolate that particular path and only that path. The path(s) below are not fixed so I can’t use the split function and select the `"tk-nuke-writenode"` path using a field (e.g. `[2]`). See example below:

`NUKE_PATH = os.environ['NUKE_PATH']`

Result:

> 'X:\pipeline\app_config\release\extensions\global\nuke;X:\pipeline\app_config\release\extensions\projects\sgtk\powerPlant\install\app_store\tk-nuke\v0.11.4\classic_startup\restart;X:/pipeline/app_config/release/extensions/projects/sgtk/powerPlant/install/app_store/tk-nuke-writenode/v1.4.1/gizmos'

`NUKE_PATH.split(os.pathsep)[2]`

Result:

> 'X:/pipeline/app_config/release/extensions/projects/sgtk/powerPlant/install/app_store/tk-nuke-writenode/v1.4.1/gizmos'

Wanted output:

> 'X:/pipeline/app_config/release/extensions/projects/sgtk/powerPlant/install/app_store/tk-nuke-writenode/v1.4.1/gizmos'

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The paths are divided by ';' so you can use something like this:

```
NUKE_PATH = os.environ['NUKE_PATH']
l = NUKE_PATH.split(';')
result = filter(lambda path: "tk-nuke-writenode" in path, l)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your paths do not contain any semicolons, you can do

```
path = 'X:\pipeline\app_config\release\extensions\global\nuke;X:\pipeline\app_config\release\extensions\projects\sgtk\powerPlant\install\app_store\tk-nuke\v0.11.4\classic_startup\restart;X:/pipeline/app_config/release/extensions/projects/sgtk/powerPlant/install/app_store/tk-nuke-writenode/v1.4.1/gizmos'
matches = [p for p in path.split(';') if 'tk-nuke-writenode' in p]
matches[0]
'X:/pipeline/app_config/release/extensions/projects/sgtk/powerPlant/install/app_store/tk-nuke-writenode/v1.4.1/gizmos'
```

This will raise an exception if no matches are found, and it may be a good idea to handle multiple matches as well.